# Displaying images with img tag in React.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Iv'e been trying to load images to a simple  tag, but it simply doesn't work. I wish to use ES6 syntax, and not dynamically injecting the image in this case:

```
import React from 'react'
import BackgroundImage from './Sparrow_icon.png';


const Icon = ({icon}) => {

    return (
        <img src={require('./Sparrow_icon.png')} alt=""/>
    )
};

export default Icon;
```

which resulted in:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICJlNTZlYThiOTQ5OWUzZmM2NTkyY2ZhMjgxNjg1YTBkMy5wbmciOw==" />
```

which displays.. nothing. 
Also, when i'm converting it with a base64 convertor- the image doesn't exist.

I'm using webpack2 with file-loader and url-loader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem is that this file is being processed by file-loader AND url-loader.

```
$ echo 'bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICJlNTZlYThiOTQ5OWUzZmM2NTkyY2ZhMjgxNjg1YTBkMy5wbmciOw==' | base64 -d
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "e56ea8b9499e3fc6592cfa281685a0d3.png";
```

Change your webpack config to only use one or the other for png files.

Comment: Interesting, It really does make a difference and i'm definitely going to check it out (why with both a 64base is generated).
Now (with file loader only) I get:
<img src="e56ea8b9499e3fc6592cfa281685a0d3.png" alt="">,
and this is a 404 error. So the src actually trying to fetch it. The problem is that the file doesn't exist. How can I handle it?

Comment: @Chen might have to adjust your publicPath in webpack config to have the right prefix. Not sure if it's different in webpack 2.

Comment: Worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<img src={require('./Sparrow_icon.png')} alt=""/>
```

with

```
<img src={BackgroundImage} alt=""/>
```

Does that work?